# Source Does not have Runnable target

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a stored procedure in oracle  and it works fine. now I wanted to create a stored procedure with in parm.  that takes Date  and simply  inserts that into where clause with in the select statement. here is what I have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE DOMESTIC
( par_start_date IN DATE) As
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO DATA
                  (   STATEMENTNUMBER,
                      STATEMENTTOTAL, 
                      STATEMENTDATE,
                      BALANCE_FORWARD,
                      CUSTID,
                      CUSTNAME,
                      STATEMENTPURCHASES,
                      STATEMENTPAYMENTS,
                      NOMAILNOPRINT,
                      SOLDTOCOUNTRYNAME,
                      CREDITZEROFLAG,
                      SOLDTOCOUNTRYCODE)

            SELECT  STATEMENTNUMBER,
                    STATEMENTTOTAL,
                    STATEMENTDATE, 
                    BALANCE_FORWARD, 
                    CUSTID,
                    CUSTNAME, 
                    STATEMENTPURCHASES,
                    STATEMENTPAYMENTS,
                    NOMAILNOPRINT,
                    SOLDTOCOUNTRYNAME,
                    CREDITZEROFLAG,
                    SOLDTOCOUNTRYCODE
                        FROM STATEMENT 
                              WHERE (STATEMENTDATE= par_start_date);
END DOMESTIC;
```

This Procedure Compiles without any error, but when I run it. I get error Stating 
**"Source Does not have Runnable target"**
Am I, missing something here ?

Comment: this dosent look like an ORA. how are you trying to run it and from where.... ?

Comment: Running it from sql Developer.

Comment: and you are able to run anything else from there ?

Comment: yes the same procedure without the in parm works fine.

Comment: Please show us the exact SQL that you use to run the procedure.

Comment: Ipress Ctrl +f11 , or the Start button

Comment: So My SQl Statement  works  when I run it from script, I think something is iffy with declaration of Spoc. Dun know if that helps or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a stored procedure with date parameter from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327024/call-a-stored-procedure-with-date-parameter-from-c-sharp)