# Call a stored procedure with date parameter from C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create and run a stored procedure with an IN parameter, which is a date. Once the date passed into the procedure I want to run a simple select statement to transfer all data into a destination table.

Assuming that source table and destination tables are exactly same, I'm using:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Test ( start_date in data ) as

Begin

   insert into Destination_table (column 1 , column2, date_Column)
   Select column1, column 2, Date_column 
     from Source_table 
    Where date_column = Start_date;
Commit;
End Test;
```

Edited ...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Procedure_TEST ( s_date IN date ) AS
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO Ps_dest_table ( Name, Salary, STATEMENTDATE )
   SELECT Name, Salary, STATEMENTDATE 
     FROM ps_Source_table 
    WHERE (statementdate = s_date)                              

END procedure_TEST;
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? or am I missing something? How can I call this from C# code?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but remove the commit.  Transaction control should be managed by the caller.  See here for exampel for C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940587/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-from-c-net

Comment: I tried this  but I get  source does not have a runnable target.Also from the program when I run this proc nothing happens.   example destination table has no data.

Comment: Well, then please update your question with the most correct details.  You get this error, " source does not have a runnable target" from C#?

Comment: I get this error in SQL Developer itself When I run  the procedure  as script. Edited the Question with the real Procedure

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the insert:  WHERE (statementdate = s_date);

Comment: added that still same problem OldProgrammer

Comment: My final comment - As I asked, please compile the procedure from sqlplus and see if that give an error to exclude any behavior of SQLdeveloper.

Comment: @ OldProgrammer  Can you tell me the syntax of executing this procedure on SQL plus ?  also, if you can make a dummy proc that is functional. So , I can compare where the mistake is in my procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct.  You have some inconsistencies in your spacing in your example, though.

```
insert into Destination_table (column 1 , column2, date_Column)
```

should be:

```
insert into Destination_table (column1 , column2, date_Column)
```

and

```
Select column1, column 2, Date_column from Source_table
```

should be:

```
Select column1, column2, Date_column from Source_table
```

what is your actual query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the guys answered your first question about the procedure.

To call it from .Net/C# you can use Oracle Data Provider .Net (ODP.Net) its a free API from Oracle, you can find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  The Problem was not with how I had the stored procedure written.  but there is a bug in the SQLDeveloper itself.  when I created the stored procedure and compiled it. It complied but did not run.  I was getting "Source does not have a runnable target." I simply closed the application and restarted it and the procedure executed without any problems.  So, anyone who has a same kind of problem.  Just, restarting the application can solve your problem pending that your procedure compiles.